# SQL Server : Join from multiple table references

Tags: sql-server, join

Forgive me for adding yet another JOIN question, but I've been stumped all day and haven't been able to find a good answer for this.

I'm trying to join 4 tables, such that they look like below:

```
QuarterID    ReviewID    SaleID    PotentialID
    1           1           1          1
    1           2           2         null
    1           3         null         2
    1           4         null        null
```

The relevant info from the tables is below

**Sale**:

```
  QuarterID
  ReviewID
  IsArchived
```

**Potential**:

```
  QuarterID
  ReviewID
  IsArchived
```

**Quarter**:

```
  ID
```

**Review**:

```
  ID
```

We can have multiple `Sales` and `Potentials` associated with one `Quarter-Review` pairing, but only one `Sale` and one `Potential` will have `IsArchived = 0` for the given `Quarter-Review` pairing.

```
SELECT 
    quarter.id    AS QID, 
    review.id     AS RID, 
    Sales.id      AS SID, 
    Potentials.id AS PID 
FROM
    dbo.quarter 
JOIN 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM dbo.sale 
     WHERE isarchived = 0) AS Sales ON Sales.quarterid = quarter.id 
JOIN 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM dbo.potential 
     WHERE isarchived = 0) AS Potentials ON Potentials.quarterid = quarter.id 
JOIN 
    dbo.review ON dbo.review.id = Sales.reviewid   
               AND dbo.review.id = Potentials.reviewid 
ORDER BY 
    quarter.id, rid
```

Using the above (there are some unnecessary columns, I know), I've managed to get the joins so that they get the 1st condition (where its all the Sales and Potentials that are in the same Quarter and Review combination, but I also want to see if there is a Quarter/Review combo with only a Sale and no Potential, if there is a Q/R combo with only a Potential and no Sale, and just every Quarter and Review combo, since there are only a few Q/R combos that have both a Sale and Potential, with almost all of the Q/R combos only having a Sale or Potential.

I guess overall the difficulty comes from needing to get the join from two intermediate tables. I can join Quarter, Sale, and Review easily, but having the Potential table joining on the same fields (ReviewID, QuarterID) as Sale is making me only get the AND, and I can't figure out an OR. I've been throwing around ORs for hours trying to get the right sequence without any luck. Help?

--Edit to include sample data--

```
Quarter
  ID
  1
  2

Review
  ID     (Other fields, not relevant to join)
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5

Sale
  ID    ReviewID    QuarterID    isArchived (Other fields, not relevant)
  1        1           1            0
  2        2           1            1
  3        2           1            0
  4        1           2            0
  5        5           1            0
  6        5           2            0

Potential
  ID    ReviewID    QuarterID    isArchived (Other fields, not relevant)
  1        1           1            0
  2        3           1            0
  3        4           2            1
  4        4           2            0
  5        5           2            0
```

Joining the above sample data, I would expect the output to look like:

```
QuarterID    ReviewID    SaleID    PotentialID
    1           1          1           1
    1           2          3          null
    1           3         null         2
    1           4         null        null
    1           5          5          null
    2           1          4          null
    2           2         null        null
    2           3         null        null
    2           4         null         4
    2           5          6           5
```

But the problem I am having is I am only returning the rows like the first and last row, where there is both a Sale and Potential for a given Quarter/Review combo, and not the ones where one or many may be null.

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to do this though I don't have the time at the moment to try something larger, but have you considered putting pieces of the query into a temp table and selecting from that?  Joins like this is where the relational model gets a bit hairy so maybe denormalize a bit into another table and use that to query on.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more it seems like I may have to do something like that to break it down into 4 separate queries to get each condition and then combine them. I'd really prefer not to if I don't have to (a solution allowing me to make an Indexed View out of this would be ideal), but I may have to.

Comment: please post some sample data and expected result

Comment: I ca't quite follow your explanation, but I suspect you either need to use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` or a `UNION ALL` with an aggregate. If you post some sample data that contains all or most edge cases it may be easier to understand.

Comment: Posted some sample data. I don't have the data in front of me, so I won't be able to run any solutions for a few hours. Thanks for your help everyone!

Comment: @wilsonl, there are 2 rows in sales referencing review_id=2  (sale_id 2, 3) but only one is present in result table. There are three rows in result table having review_id but nulls in both saleid and potentialid - how did you link Q and R? both cases are not clear.

Comment: Right, so saleid 2 and 3 both reference reviewid 2, but saleid 2 has isArchived = 1, and shouldn't appear in the solution. There is currently no linking between Quarter and Review other than the Sale and Potential in the middle with a reference each to both Quarter and Review. In the case of where there is a Quarter and Review without no Sale or Potentials, I would like the solution to still show Quarter and Review with nulls for Sale and Potential.

Comment: So there must be all reviews shown for each quarter no matter whether there is any matching sales/potential in that quarter, right? Then @Amit's answer is correct. Cross join + two left joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly (some sample data will help) but I think you mean that you need all the combinations of Quarter and Review and then any related Sale and Potential data for each combination of Quarter and Review. If that is what you need, then try the below query:

```
SELECT [Quarter].ID AS QID, Review.ID AS RID, Sales.ID AS SID, Potentials.ID AS PID FROM [Quarter]
CROSS JOIN [Review]
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Sale WHERE IsArchived = 0) Sales ON [Quarter].ID = Sales.QuarterID AND [Review].ID = Sales.ReviewID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Potential WHERE IsArchived = 0) Potentials ON [Quarter].ID = Potentials.QuarterID AND [Review].ID = Potentials.ReviewID
```

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted. Thanks for your help everyone!